# Optimal distribution of points in a cone

Tags: geometry

See https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46463/is-there-an-optimum-set-of-colors-for-10-players

I think a good solution would be to distribute points in the HSV cone in such a way that they are as evenly spread as possible.

I can calculate the sum of distances for all the points, and the find the maximum, but how to distribute the points?

How to approach such a problem?

Comment: The tag (distribution-theory) refers to a completely dfferent subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a general non-numerical solution.
One way to do this numerically would be to use [simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) or a similar approach. To use this method, you first define a energy function between each pair of points on the cone. For instance you could use:
$$d(h_1,s_1,v_1,h_2,s_2,v_2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(h_1-h_2)^2+(s_1-s_2)^2+(v_1-v_2)^2}}$$
Then randomly choose 10 points on the cone, and with each step move each point a small random amount, recalculate the total energy, and decide whether you want to keep the new set of points. Continue iterating, and with a correct choice of the [annealing schedule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing#The_annealing_schedule), you should converge to the "optimal" solution for the function you chose. This method has been used [quite successfully](http://estamine.net/fc0809/JJFerreira-fisica_computacional.pdf) on the [Thomson problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_problem), which is quite similar to yours.

Comment: Nice reference, thanks. This look a lot like the Self Organising Maps that I know from the AI field. I was hoping there was a nice analytical solution.. But your solution will yield a (local?) optimum.

Comment: It will yield a global optimum (with the right choice of schedule) - that's why simulated annealing is such a good choice :)